# Relations between odom coordinate and map coordinate system when create a map？

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I‘m using slam_gmapping to create a map.I can successfully created a map,but I don't know the relationship between odom coordinate and map coordinate.

In my opinion,both map  and odom coordinate frame is fixed,but when I move my robot,the position of odom coordinate frame changed.!

I want to know why odom frame is changed and how to compute odom's value?  Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233221/relations-between-odom-coordinate-and-map-coordinate-system-when-create-a-map%EF%BC%9F/) by [Damo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26732/damo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In an ideal world, `odom` and  `map` will both be fixed and, when doing SLAM, at the same place.
However, the world is not ideal. [citation needed]

When running SLAM (or any localization algorithm, for that matter), you account for errors in the odometry using the respective algorithm. In ROS, the typical way to do this is to adjust the `map->odom` transform. This allows you to publish the transform from `odom->base_link` from your [robot](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) and other nodes to access it.

So the transform `odom->base_link` is what the robot thinks it has traveled based on the (noisy and inaccurate) odometry, the transform `map->odom` is the correction of the noisy odometry provided by the localization algorithm, resulting in the robot pose in the world displayed by the `map->odom->base_link` transform.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Damo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26732/damo/) on 2016-04-29**:
Thanks for your answer! And,do you know the theory of map-->odom transform?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-29**:
What do you mean by "theory of `map->odom` transform"? This is the classical robot localization/SLAM problem...
Note, though, that localization/SLAM actually estimates `map->base_link` and then you "subtract" `odom->base_link` to get `map->odom` as tf requires a tree structure...